# How to send Rails Mailer (reminder email) upon if statement NOT by a user action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, delayed-job, worker, mailer

Until now, all of my rails mailers are triggered by a user action (creating account, sending requests, etc). However now I'd like to send out a (reminder) email without a user action, but instead if two statements are true (time passed & enum status pending).
What would be the best way to set this up? Could I possibly use a worker?
Thanks,
Robin

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rake task to send the reminder and then create a cron job to run it periodically. For this thing I recommend the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Here you have an example of how to create a rake task -> http://railsguides.net/how-to-generate-rake-task/